# How do I programmatically find the argparse arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a series of Python scripts. Some use `argparse` to process the command line arguments passed to them; others don't.

I want, through another Python script, to walk through all those scripts, and list, for each script, the arguments it accepts, whether they are mandatory or optional, what are their types, and what is the default value, if any.

What would be a convenient way to do that?

I thought about executing those scripts with `--help` argument, and parsing `stdout`, but that has four caveats:

- Parsing `stdout` may not be that simple.
- My application would be particularly fragile: whenever the format of output by `argparse` changes, it could break.
- Some scripts may not support the `--help` argument, and start to perform their respective tasks; I don't want that.
- Default values are not included in the help.

I also thought about importing the scripts, but it doesn't look like it would help. After all, most have the arguments processing block conditioned by `if __name__ == "__main__":`, so the code of interest won't even execute.

What are my other options?

Comment: You could open them as text and parse for `add_argument` for example but that sounds like a hard job with many edge-cases that can easily go wrong

Comment: @Tomerikoo: there would be indeed a lot of edge cases, starting by a simple fact that a script may `import` other modules, and the `argparse` code may be in them, instead of the primary script.

Comment: It would probably be easiest to try executing what you can with `--help`, or maybe `-h` also, parsing the resulting stdout, and then looking at what didn't work and examining alternate approaches as necessary. There's almost certainly not one method that'll work for everything, so you might as well try what you can.

Comment: Search the scripts for `argparse` imports and uses may work in simple cases, but is hardly robust, and in the long run tedious.  Sometimes scripts put the parser creation in a function, which is called in the `__name__` block (or at least the `parse_args` step).  Once a parser is created, its `_actions` list has all the necessary information in its `Action` objects.  For a start you might create and examine a `parser` in an interactive python session.

Comment: Another option would be to use the [AST library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to parse the scripts. However, it's probably a lot more effort than to just use something like `grep`.

Comment: Just an idea: with `argparse`, monkey-patch the `.parse_args` method to dump the all details from the parser configuration you are interested in and then exit the program. Then start the script.

Comment: Maybe you could see how [argcomplete](https://kislyuk.github.io/argcomplete/) does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `ipython` session, this gives an idea of the objects that are created by a simple parser script.  `add_argument` creates an `Action` subclass object, puts in a list, and also returns it.  Since these are Python objects, their attributes can be examined (and even modified).

```
In [1]: import argparse
In [2]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [3]: type(parser)
Out[3]: argparse.ArgumentParser
In [4]: print(parser)
ArgumentParser(prog='ipython3', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)
In [5]: parser.add_argument('-f','--foo')
Out[5]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['-f', '--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
In [6]: parser.add_argument('bar')
Out[6]: _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='bar', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
In [7]: parser._actions
Out[7]: 
[_HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['-f', '--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='bar', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)]
In [8]: vars(parser._actions[1])
Out[8]: 
{'option_strings': ['-f', '--foo'],
 'dest': 'foo',
 'nargs': None,
 'const': None,
 'default': None,
 'type': None,
 'choices': None,
 'required': False,
 'help': None,
 'metavar': None,
 'container': <argparse._ArgumentGroup at 0x7f8a1f73dac8>}
```

The help produced by `-h` or `parser.format_help` is created from these objects - the `parser` and the `Actions` (and `groups`). Parsing also works from these.  So everything is present.  But I would not to deduce all this from my own reading of the `parser` instructions - that would amount to recreating the `argparse.py` code.